# How do I get a Ruby IO stream for a Paperclip Attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, io, paperclip

I have an application that stores uploaded CSV files using the Paperclip gem.

Once uploaded, I would like to be able to stream the data from the uploaded file into code that reads it line-by-line and loads it into a data-staging table in Postgres.

I've gotten this far in my efforts, where `data_file.upload` is a Paperclip CSV Attachment

```
io = StringIO.new(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(data_file.upload).read, 'r')
```

Even though ^^ works, the problem is that - as you can see - it loads the entire file into memory as a honkin' Ruby String, and Ruby String garbage is notoriously bad for app performance.

Instead, I want a Ruby IO object that supports use of e.g., `io.gets` so that the IO object handles buffering and cleanup, and the whole file doesn't sit as one huge string in memory.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Hmm, `Paperclip::AbstractAdapter#read` does accept 2 params, the first for the number of characters to read, the second some mysterious string called `buffer` ... but that doesn't really help, since what I really want to do is read to the next newline.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

With some help (from StackOverflow, of course), I was able to suss this myself.

In my PaperClip AR model object, I now have the following:

```
# Done this way so we get auto-closing of the File object
def yielding_upload_as_readable_file
  # It's quite annoying that there's not 1 method that works for both filesystem and S3 storage
  open(filesystem_storage? ? upload.path : upload.url) { |file| yield file }
end

def filesystem_storage?
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] == :filesystem
end
```

... and, I consume it in another model like so:

```
data_file.yielding_upload_as_readable_file do |file|
  while line = file.gets
    next if line.strip.size == 0
    ... process line ...
  end
end
```